# Trying to encode Special keywords from Value in react

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, spfx, spfx-webparts, react

I am trying to filter the special keyword value from SharePoint list. Filter query doesn't work when filter the value.

I am applying the `encodeURIComponent` solution for encode the special keyword. But special keyword value doesn't encode(Screenshot attached).

[image]

Please suggest how to filter special keyword value.

Comment: Which special keywords you are getting in the `RequestID`?

Comment: I am getting below special keyword in RequestID:- '&', ',', '-', '%'.

Comment: Can you paste the value of `encodeURIVal` variable also?

Comment: I am checking to see how things are going there on this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Generally , SharePoint API doesn't support special keywords such as `#$$#@^&` in the url as a parameter

`EncodeURIComponent` function will not encode all the special characters

You can try below code for encoding special characters:

```
function fixedEncodeURIComponent(src) {  
    return encodeURIComponent(src).replace(/[']/g, function (c) {  
    return '%' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16) + '%' + 
   c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16);  
  });  
 }
```